# Show that $V^{\mu} = (\cos\phi, -\cot\theta \sin\phi)$ is a Killing's vector on the 2-sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, general-relativity

I have been asked to show that $W^{\mu} = (\cos(\phi), -\cot(\theta) \sin(\phi))$ is a Killing's vector on the 2-sphere, where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are functions of the parameter s.

Our approach was first to use the Euler-Lagrange method to find the geodesics. This gave $\ddot{\theta} = J \cot(\theta) \dot{\phi}$, where $J = \dot{\phi}\sin^{2}(\theta)$ is a conserved quantity along geodesics.

Then, we wanted to show that $ \frac{d}{ds} (W_\mu V^\mu) = \frac{d}{ds}(g_{\mu \nu}W^\nu V^\nu) = \frac{d}{ds} (\cos(\phi) \dot{\theta} - \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\dot{\phi}) = 0$, where the metric for the 2-sphere is given by $ds^{2} = d\theta^{2} + \sin^{2}(\theta)d\phi^{2}$.

The expansion of the above line should yield the following, $\frac{d}{ds} (W_\mu V^\mu) = \cot(\phi)(\ddot{\theta} - J\cot(\theta)\dot{\phi}) = 0$. However, I am not sure how to get from the previous line to this last one. When I do the differentiation, I get some cross terms in $\dot{\theta}\dot{\phi}$ and $\ddot{\phi}$ occurring. I am unsure if I am differentiating things wrong, or if they should cancel somehow. Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Tip: For trig functions, use `\cos`, `\sin`, etc.

Comment: Is your parametrization $s (\phi, \theta)$ or $s (\phi, \theta)$? (even better: can you write down explicitly $s$)?

Answer (score 2):

PSA: I am using the [mathematics convention](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) for spherical coordinates. I.e, I am using the coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$, *in that order*, where $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle (coordinate 1) and $\phi$ is the polar angle (coordinate 2).

To show that a vector $\boldsymbol v$ is a Killing vector, you need to show that it satisfies Killing's equation:
$$\nabla_i v_j+\nabla_jv_i=0$$
We have the vector
$$\boldsymbol v=\begin{bmatrix}
 -\cot \phi\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}^\intercal$$
Its corresponding dual components are
$$v_i=g_{ij}v^j$$
Recall that on the two sphere (of radius $1$), the metric is
$$\mathbf{g} =\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin^{2} \phi  & 0
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$
You can verify that
$$v_1=g_{1j}v^j=g_{1~1}v^1=-\sin^2\phi\cot\phi\sin\theta=-\sin\phi\cos\phi\sin\theta \\v_2=g_{2j}v^j =g_{2~2}v^2=v^2=\cos\theta$$
Hence
$$\boldsymbol{v}_\flat=\begin{bmatrix}
 -\sin\phi\cos\phi\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}$$
The covariant derivatives are
$$\nabla_iv_j=\partial_j v_i-\Gamma^k_{ij}v_k$$
Recall again that the Christoffel symbols on the two sphere (of radius $1$) are
$$ \Gamma^1_{1~2}=\Gamma^1_{2~1}=\cot\phi \\ \ \Gamma^2_{1~1}=-\cos\phi\sin\phi$$
With all others zero. Let's return to Killing's equation
$$\nabla_i v_j+\nabla_jv_i=0$$
And compute all the components. First $i=j=1$:
$$\nabla_1v_1=\partial_1v_1-\Gamma^k_{1~1}v_k \\ =\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(-\sin\phi\cos\phi\sin\theta)-\Gamma^{1}_{1~1}v_1-\Gamma^2_{1~1}v_2 \\ =-\sin\phi\cos\phi\cos\theta-(-\cos\phi\sin\phi)\cos\theta=0$$
Now let's do $i=j=2$:
$$\nabla_2v_2=\partial_2v_2-\Gamma^k_{2~2}v_k$$
All of the $\Gamma^k_{2~2}$ are zero, and $\partial_2 v_2=\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}(\cos\theta)=0$ hence $\nabla_2v_2=0$. Finally let's do $i=1,j=2$. Since Killing's equation is symmetric wrt to $i,j$ this covers the $i=2,j=1$ case as well.
$$\nabla_1v_2+\nabla_2v_1= \left[\partial_2v_1-\Gamma^k_{1~2}v_k\right]+\left[\partial_1v_2-\Gamma^k_{2~1}v_k\right]$$
It looks like we need to use the product rule to calculate $\partial_2v_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}(-\sin\phi\cos\phi\sin\theta)$ but you can save yourself a lot of work using the identity
$$\sin\phi\cos\phi=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\phi)$$
So,
$$\nabla_1v_2+\nabla_2v_1=\left[-\cos(2\phi)\sin\theta-\cot\phi(-\sin\phi\cos\phi\sin\theta)\right]+\left[(-\sin\theta)-\cot\phi(-\sin\phi\cos\phi\sin\theta)\right]$$
We can simplify this:
$$\nabla_1v_2+\nabla_2v_1=2\cot\phi(\sin\phi\cos\phi\sin\theta)-\sin\theta(1+\cos(2\phi)) \\ =2\cos^2\phi\sin\theta-\sin\theta(1+\cos(2\phi)) \\ =\sin\theta(2\cos^2\phi-(1+\cos(2\phi)))=0$$

I'll let you verify the trigonometric identity $2\cos^2\phi=1+\cos(2\phi)$ on your own. Hence we have shown $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a Killing vector field.